# Update Word document with large set of paragraphs using custom styles

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am processing a word document that has about 6000 paragraphs using VB script macro. I have to format each paragraph with a user style (i.e. font size, color, bold, italics).

The script works on a small document 10 pages or so, but on a 200+ pages the performance becomes very slow and often it will run out of memory.

The entry subroutine is called `NormilizeToBarlow11()`

```vb
Sub NormilizeToBarlow11()
    call initStyleIndex()
    Dim currentFont as Integer
    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    ' Check if Word is running and an active document is open
    If objWord.Documents.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There is no active document in Word."
        objWord.Quit
        WScript.Quit
    End If
    DelTempStyles
    Set objDoc = objWord.ActiveDocument


    For Each objPara In objDoc.Paragraphs

        If objPara.Style = "Normal" Then '
            objPara.Range.Select
            if ( Selection.Font.Size > 72 ) Then
                currentFont = 11 
            End If
            If(Selection.Font.Bold = False And Selection.Font.Italic = False) Then
                    Call NomilizeFonts(False,False, 11)
                ElseIf(Selection.Font.Bold = True) Then
                    Call NomilizeFonts(True,False,currentFont)
                ElseIf(Selection.Font.Italic = True) Then
                    call NomilizeFonts(False,True,currentFont)
            End If  
        End If
    Next

    ActiveDocument.Save
    Set objDoc = Nothing
    Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub

Function NomilizeFonts( BoldFlag As Boolean,ItalicFlag As Boolean, FontSize As Integer )
    styleIndex=styleIndex + 1
    stylePrefix = "NormilizeDocText" & styleIndex

    On Error GoTo ErrTrap
    Set myStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles.Add(Name:=stylePrefix, _
        Type:=wdStyleTypeCharacter)
     
    With myStyle.Font
     .Bold = BoldFlag
     .Italic = ItalicFlag
     .Name = "Barlow"
     .Size = FontSize
     .AutomaticallyUpdate = False
    End With
    
    ErrTrap:
        Selection.Range.Style = stylePrefix

End Function
Function DelTempStyles()
'Delete all unused styles, except for built-in styles,
'in the current document.
Dim s As Style
For Each s In ActiveDocument.Styles
    'Only execute With if current s isn't a built-in style.
    If s.BuiltIn = False Then
        With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Style = s.NameLocal
            .Execute FindText:="", Format:=True
            If .Found = True Then s.Delete
        End With
    End If
Next
End Function


Function initStyleIndex()
    styleIndex = 0
End Function
```

As you can see the script creates a new Style for each paragraph - lots of styles. I did try to use/reuse an single style, select a paragraph, update, but that is not work working since every new style update will be applied to all earlier paragraphs.

I would expect script to run a 1-2 minutes or less.

Comment: The unique number of combinations of Bold+Italic+FontSize is likely much less than 6000, so why not create one new style for each unique combination, instead of 6000 styles, many of which will be the same?

Comment: I second Tim Williams' suggestion. You will also end up with a smaller and less complex file doing that. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/stylesImportance.htm